# Git push doesn't work for Dokku on Azure

Tags: azure, ssh, dokku

I have a trouble making *git push* work for me for *Dokku* instance on *Azure*. In particular, it was installed using [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dokku-vm). For installation I used the latest Dokku version (0.10.3) with Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem, I think, is that a special admin User is created from this template. So, I can ssh using its name and it works pretty well, but when I try to git push to remote (which is *dokku@...*) it prompts for a password. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277169/dokku-asking-for-password-when-trying-to-git-push) on StackOverflow, but I don't see any obvious solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on the issue you filed in our issue tracker, you will still need to setup the ssh user via the web ui we start for your server. Once you set that up, you should be able to push code.